# Python 3 vk_api не работает VkUpload

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, type-error

Пытаюсь исполнить код:

```
upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk)
photoFile = '/root/signLast.png'
photo = upload.photo(photos=photoFile, album_id='252572440')
```

Интерпретатор ругается:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Фрагмент офф. документации:

```
photo = upload.photo(  # Подставьте свои данные
        '/root/3301.jpg',
        album_id=200851098,
        group_id=74030368
)
```

Это особенности языка? Если я уберу аргументы, то интерпретатор выдаст следующее:

```
TypeError: photo() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'photos' and 'album_id'
```

И как тут быть? Отправлять аргументы кортежем? Не работает. Помогите, кто с vk_api работал.

Answer (score 1):

Обновите версию vk_api. В новой версии таких проблем нет. А загружать фото можно так:

```
from vk_api import VkUpload
upload = VkUpload(vk5)
CDV = ["art_otvet.jpg"]
photo_list = upload.photo(CDV,255843722)
owner_id = photo_list[0]["owner_id"]
id_own = photo_list[0]["id"
attachment ='photo{}_{}'.format(owner_id,id_own)
```